# Uses SeekBar to adjust the data displayed in UI from my Room database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I wrote code that takes the value of the progress bar in my Android app which influences what is displayed on the UI. If the user's progress bar value is above or below a certain number, data will be either displayed or not displayed. Here is the following code:

```java
    public class DetailsFirstTabFragment extends Fragment {

    private DetailsFirstTabViewModel viewModel;
    private RecyclerView recentThings;
    private TextView progressTextView;
    final RecentThings adapter = new RecentThings();
    private List<ThingEntity> thingEntities;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        viewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DetailsFirstTabViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first_page_expense_details, container, false);

        recentThings = root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_recent_things);
        recentThings.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recentThings.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recentThings.setAdapter(adapter);

        final float[] totalSum = {0};
        final TextView textViewTotalSum = root.findViewById(R.id.textViewStuffTotalSum);

        SeekBar seekBar = root.findViewById(R.id.seekBarStuffDetails);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);

        progressTextView = root.findViewById(R.id.textViewProgress);

        viewModel.getAllThings().observe(this, new Observer<List<ThingEntity>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<ThingEntity> thingEntities) {
                for (ThingEntity thing : thingEntities) {
                    totalSum[0] = totalSum[0] + thing.getThingAmount();
                }
                textViewTotalSum.setText(String.valueOf(totalSum[0]));
                adapter.setThingEntityList(thingEntities);
                setThingEntities(thingEntities);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
    }

    public void setThingEntities(List<ThingsEntity> thingEntities) {
        this.thingEntities = thingEntities;
    }
    SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progressValue = 0;

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            String progressText = "Date " + String.valueOf(progress);
            progressValue = progress;
            progressTextView.setText(progressText);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            List<ThingEntity> shownThings = new ArrayList<>();
            for (ThingEntity entity : thingEntities) {
                if (entity.getThingAmount() > progressValue) {
                    shownThings.add(entity);
                }
            }
            adapter.setThingEntityList(shownThings);
        }
    };
}
```

So I am wondering if I am treating this need in a good way. I am not sure if getting all the entities and then looping over them to see if the condition is met to display is a good implementation. Additionally, I am wondering if the rest of the code makes sense. I am also not sure if I am creating viewmodels and observers in a resource-mindful manner. Any insight to these concerns (or ones I have not observed) would be very much appreciated (I am a beginner :))